# distance transform algorithms in scipy

Tags: python, scipy

Since there are a lot of different algorithms for distance transformations (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426136/fastest-available-algorithm-for-distance-transform)), I have some difficulty to understand how scipy's distance_transform_edt and distance_transform_bf work. Are there any detailed descriptions availible for that?

Comment: Google generally helps with that. First link that came up when I googled `scipy's distance_transform_edt` was a link to scipy documentation for that function with explanation and example...

Comment: From what I have found in the docs there is only an explanation WHAT it does, and of course some examples. I don't need a distance transformation definition, but some information on HOW the algorithm actually works...

Comment: Ahh, gotcha, sorry, I wasn't reading closely enough. You want all the nitty-gritty details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following through the source...

**`distance_transform_edt`** ends up at [code](http://www.sourcecodebrowser.com/python-scipy/0.7.0/ni__morphology_8c_source.html#l00909) starting with the following helpful comment:

```
/* Exact euclidean feature transform, as described in: C. R. Maurer,
   Jr., R. Qi, V. Raghavan, "A linear time algorithm for computing
   exact euclidean distance transforms of binary images in arbitrary
   dimensions. IEEE Trans." PAMI 25, 265-270, 2003. */

int NI_EuclideanFeatureTransform(PyArrayObject* input,
           PyArrayObject *sampling_arr,
           PyArrayObject* features)
```

And **`distance_transform_bf`** ends up at a [function](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/81c096001974f0b5efe29ec83b54f725cc681540/scipy/ndimage/src/ni_morphology.c#L526) which is looks to be a brute force calculation.  But here the algorithm is also well described in the main documentation and elsewhere that turn up in a basic search.