# How to I create a distance image for a chamfer algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I think I know how the chamfer algorithm works:
[image]

Basicly take an images where every pixels greyscale is its own distance to the next closest edge pixel.

Then take an reference image (20px*30px) and try every possible position on the distance image for an image ( (100px*100px) ((100-20)*(100-30))=5600 positions )

Save the sum of all pixel whith their equivalent pixel on the refernce image and then you take the best match.

The problem is I have no idea how to turn the edge image (feature image) and turn it into the distance image.

I know I could just create a giant loop but that seams very inefficient. So whats an efficient way to turn the feature image into the distance image?

Comment: Are you using some image processing library (eventually please specify which one) or trying to write your own implementation? Usually these operations are already available in libraries, i.e.for  OpenCV you can see here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html

Comment: If you're implementing it yourself you can see the references here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426136/fastest-available-algorithm-for-distance-transform